# Android when spinner selected one of the item, it will show the information in listview according to their data name from database

Tags: java, android

```
public class AddMark extends AppCompatActivity {

    SQLControlerSubject dbconnection;
    Spinner spinnerM;
    TextView tv_markId, tv_markSub,tv_markType;
    TextView tv_listmarkId,tv_listmarkName,tv_listmarkMark,tv_listmarkType,tv_listmarkDescription;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_mark);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddMark);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (spinnerM.getSelectedItem() != null) {

                        tv_markId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mark_id);
                        tv_markSub = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.markSub);
                        tv_markType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mark_tutorlec);

                        String markId = tv_markId.getText().toString();
                        String markSub = tv_markSub.getText().toString();
                        String markType = tv_markType.getText().toString();

                        Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddMarkInside.class);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("markId", markId);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("markSub", markSub);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("markType", markType);

                        startActivity(modify_intent);
                    }
                    else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select a subject", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });


        // **************************Spinner view******************************

        dbconnection = new SQLControlerSubject(this);
        dbconnection.openDatabase();
        spinnerM = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerMark);
        Cursor cursor = dbconnection.readSubjectMark();

        String[] from = new String[] {
                DBhelperSubject.SUBJECT_ID,
                DBhelperSubject.SUBJECT_NAME,
                DBhelperSubject.SUBJECT_TYPE
        };
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.mark_id,
                R.id.markSub,
                R.id.mark_tutorlec
        };

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapterMark = new SimpleCursorAdapter
                    (AddMark.this, R.layout.row_format_mark, cursor, from, to);
            adapterMark.notifyDataSetChanged();
            spinnerM.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(adapterMark, R.layout.spinner_show_nothing, this));




        // **************************List View******************************

                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMark);
                Cursor cursorM = dbconnection.readMark();

                String[] a = new String[]{
                        DBhelperSubject.MARK_ID,
                        DBhelperSubject.SUBJECT_NAME,
                        DBhelperSubject.SUBJECT_TYPE,
                        DBhelperSubject.MARK_MARKS,
                        DBhelperSubject.MARK_DESCRIPTION
                };

                int[] b = new int[]{
                        R.id.list_mark_id,
                        R.id.list_mark_name,
                        R.id.list_mark_type,
                        R.id.list_mark_mark,
                        R.id.list_mark_description
                };

                SimpleCursorAdapter adapterM = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        AddMark.this, R.layout.row_format_list_mark, cursorM, a, b);

                adapterM.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.setAdapter(adapterM);


                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        tv_listmarkId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_mark_id);
                        tv_listmarkName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_mark_name);
                        tv_listmarkType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_mark_type);
                        tv_listmarkMark = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_mark_mark);
                        tv_listmarkDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_mark_description);


                        String listmarkId = tv_listmarkId.getText().toString();
                        String listmarkName = tv_listmarkName.getText().toString();
                        String listmarkType = tv_listmarkType.getText().toString();
                        String listmarkMark = tv_listmarkMark.getText().toString();
                        String listmarkDescription = tv_listmarkDescription.getText().toString();


                        Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateMark.class);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("listmarkId", listmarkId);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("listmarkName", listmarkName);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("listmarkType", listmarkType);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("listmarkMark", listmarkMark);
                        modify_intent.putExtra("listmarkDescription", listmarkDescription);
                        startActivity(modify_intent);
                    }
                }); 
    } 
}
```

**Desired outcome:** when a user selects a subject called "Math", it should show all the math marks in list view according to the `mark_name`.
When the user chooses nothing, it should leave it blank.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by creating an inner class that implements `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`.  Override it's two methods:

> onItemSelected( )
>   Callback method to be invoked when an item in this
>   view has been selected.
>
> onNothingSelected( )
>   Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this view.

Now, set an object of this class as the listener on your spinner. Something like:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new MyItemSelectedListener() );
```

Now go back and provide a proper definition to those two methods.